# How to make this shape with css?

Tags: css, shapes

Please check out this image:

[image: http://alexking.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/ios-shortcut-button-510x358.png]

Look at the part that says 'keyboard'

I want that shape but facing the other way (right) and not curved.

I know this is a pentagon but its not the standard type so its hard to find the name or type of this shape to learn how to make it in css. Any ideas on how to make it!?!?

Thanks guys,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mimicking the iPhone design purely in CSS is nearly impossible. However:

I found iWebKit, written by a guy who spent a lot of time on just that task. He did the navigation buttons with border images.
You can take a look at it at http://snippetspace.com/ . It's free to download, I think.
Looking at the demo code, you can easily see how the buttons work.
iWebKit is only for webkit browsers, but it does not take a lot of work to adapt to other browsers (just add -moz or -o lines where it says -webkit in the CSS).

Answer (score 2):

It's a rounded rectangle and a triangle (or a rotated square).  To make it in "CSS" would require some hacks.  I suggest you use a background image.

Comment: I agree. Background image here would be your best and safest option. Any fancy shapes you do with CSS3 may not render well in all browsers.

Comment: Well, he could do it with CSS triangles (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), but it's a lot of markup for a single button.